# The stock answer for hosting doesn't always work

Tags: discussion

[This guy](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/27728/dedicated-servers-is-one-better-then-two-for-lamp-pseudo-ha-setup) is quite correct, he has a good question, the stock answer isn't good enough to help him.

Answer (score 2):

> What are people out there doing for pseodu high availability good
>   performance setups under $400/month?

The question meets the same criteria that the catch-all was intended to address - the asker has presented requirements (note how both HA and failover are explicitly mentioned in the question - this is not a case of not knowing the terminology) and is polling for opinions.

Comment: I agree if he has a price in mind knows what he wants, Google is his best answer. Everyone else is going to be answering with their preferred service providers and giving opinions on others.